# Grub command line opening when selecting Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I installed Ubuntu using Wubi. Everything was working file when yesterday, I opened the Update Center and installed all the necessary updates. Now when I restart my machine and it prompts the dual boot option. Selecting Ubuntu now, opens a Grub command line window and the prompt waits to type-in any command. Ubuntu is not starting automatically.

What happened to the auto-load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% sure that the problem is with a Kernel update. Basically you installed a new brain to ubuntu but the update process forgot to tell the body to connect to it! :-/

If this applies to you, there is [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/484799). Bug comment #3 and #7 seem to contain a workaround for manually booting the old version of the kernel.

I would add - to that thread - that if you manage to boot ubuntu with the old kernel, you could try to issue the command

```
sudo update-grub2
```

which *should* find out the new kernel and rebuild the normal Grub menu.

**EDIT**
You should really visit the launchpad bug to check out if progress being made and new (hopefully easier workarounds), however, as of 27/11/09 16.25 GMT the following is the most complete solution provided there.

> At the grub prompt enter:
>
> `linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-14-generic root=/dev/sda1 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash`
>
> `initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-14-generic`
>
> `boot`
>
> (if it doesn't work, change sda1 to sda2 or sda3 or ..., and please don't load kernel ...-15-...!)

Comment: How to load the old kernel? And also what is the default name of Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: @Rohit - Follow the link to the bug report, look at comment number 3.

Comment: mac could you put the commands from that post into the answer. I was going to edit your post but don't have enough rep here.

Comment: @Jeremy - (1) Did this answer fixed for you (I just saw your comment under the question). (2) I included the code to boot the image in the answer. I still think is a not-so-good idea though to crystallize here a solution that is likely to be improved in a matter of hours on launchpad (the code I pasted there, for example, is from just 3 hours ago...)

Comment: @mac, yes this is what fixed it for me. even though there isn't a permanent fix (other than leaving the PC on). Thanks for posting the code.

Comment: this fix no longer works and the same issue was experienced here...complete reinstall needed.